# Spring Boot detect missing Translation

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, internationalization

I'm using Spring Boot v2.4.1 and I have different `message.properties` for different languages. For example `message.properties`, `message-fr.properties`, `message-pt.properties` and so on.

Normally, I insert messages in the default language (`message.properties`) as I work and the need for a new localized text appears. If I'm inspired in the same moment I add it to the default language I add it to all the other languages. But I'm not inspired 100% of the time.

So I (or my client) realize a translation is missing when we switch from the default language to any other.

FWIW I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle

I'd like to know if there's a way (maybe an IDE or Gradle plugin) to rise an error if a translation is missing. I mean a message-key is present in the default language `.properties` file but it's not in the others.

#### UPDATE

Also, I know that Android Studio (which is base on intelliJ and uses Gradle) throws and error if a translation is missing. I'd like to reproduce that same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Settings(Properties) | Editor | Inspections | Properties files | **Inconsistent resource bundle** inspection that you can run from Analyze | **Insect Code** or **Run Inspection by Name** actions.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! In fact, I found several other warnings from inspection, LOL. Do you know if I can trigger an inspection by name with a gradle task? So I can find missing translation upon build.